# InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available

Tags: python, ssl

I want to setup python project from CentOS to windows. While "**pip install requirement.txt**" getting following error:

```
c:\python27\lib\site-
packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: 
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

InsecurePlatformWarning
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requirements.txt
```

Please help/guide me. I' new with these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the packages one by one from `requirements.txt` and when you find the one that is throwing this error, try to look for a solution for that specific package.